# Synchronization algorithm between two entities?

Tags: algorithm, synchronization

Suppose that I have two entities, `node A` and `node B`. `node A` stores certain variables during runtime and `node B` has the responsibility of permanently storing these variables in a separate database.

At any point in time, `node A` and/or `node B` might be "dead" (i.e. crashed/not executed yet/etc.). I am looking for an algorithm which will synchronize the values of variables in `node A` and in the database according to the most recent (timestamp-wise) candidate. Some case scenarios:

1. `node B` is working and the database holds variable `x=5`. `node A` comes online (is executed). The synchronization algorithm assigns `5` to the variable `x` in `A`
2. `node A` is working and holds a value of variable `y=10`. `node B` is executed. The synchronization algorithm realizes that the value of `y` in the database is older than the timestamp associated to the variable `y` in  `nodeA`, thus `y` in the database is overwritten with value `10`
3. `node A` and `node B` are running. `node A`'s variable `z` gets updated to value `17`. The synchronization algorithm updates the value of variable `z` in the database also to `17`

I can sit and think of an algorithm to do this myself, of course. My question is - does an established algorithm for this type of synchronization already exist?

Comment: you've described in short how CouchDB works! =) maybe you can find something useful in the souce code, since it's open https://github.com/apache/couchdb.